# JPQL with Group by clause in SQL Server database not working

Tags: sql-server, spring-data-jpa, jpql, jpa-2.0

I am new to SQL Server database. The below JPQL query is not getting executed and not throwing any errors. Just my application hanging over at this query. This code is working fine with MySQL database, but not with SQL Server(2019) database.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT R.riskType, count(distinct V.bname) FROM RiskViolation V JOIN V.job J JOIN V.risk R WHERE J.id = ?1 GROUP BY R.riskType ")
public List<Object[]> sodUserByRiskType(Long jobId);
```

But when I run the below converted sql query directly in the SQL Server database, it is working fine.

```
select count(distinct riskviolat0_.bname) as col_1_0_, risklog2_.risk_type as col_0_0_ from risk_violation riskviolat0_ inner join analysis_job analysisjo1_ on riskviolat0_.job_id=analysisjo1_.id inner join risk_log risklog2_ on riskviolat0_.risk_id=risklog2_.id where analysisjo1_.id=? group by risklog2_.risk_type;
```

Here are the Java entity classes which are used in JPQL query:

**RiskViolation.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "risk_violation")
public class RiskViolation {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "job_id")
private AnalysisJob job;

private String bname;

private String riskName;

private String violations;

@Column(name = "violated", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
private boolean violated;

@Column(name = "simulation", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
private boolean simulation;

@Column(name = "mitigation_name")
private String mitigationName;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "risk_id")
private RiskLog risk;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "riskViolation", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<RuleViolation> ruleViolations;
}
```

**AnalysisJob.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "analysis_job")
public class AnalysisJob {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "profile_name")
private String profileName;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private AnalysisProfileLog profileLog;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

@Column(name = "started_on")
private Date startedOn;

@Column(name = "completed_on")
private Date completedOn;

@Column(name = "completion_message")
private String completionMessage;

@Column(name = "percent_completed")
private float percentCompleted;

@Column(name = "run_by")
private String runBy;

@Column(name = "removed", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
private boolean removed;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<JobResultData> resultData;

@Column(name = "pos_analysis", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
private boolean posAnalysis;

@Column(name = "submitted", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
private boolean submitted;

@Column(name = "position_id")
private String positionId;
}
```

**RiskLog.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "risk_log")
public class RiskLog {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private Long jobId;

private String name;

private String riskDescription;

private String riskCondition;

private String businessProcess;

@Column(name = "business_sub_process")
private String subProc;

private String riskType;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "riskLog", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
protected List<RuleLog> rules;
}
```

Do I need to make any changes to the query and entity classes to make it work?

Here is [Query Plan URL](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryx3_80LK)

[Estimated Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryx3_80LK)

[Actual Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1-ganCUK)

[Query Plan with Actual Rows](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rylmU6AIK)

Comment: Please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. To get a running query plan, run this in SSMS while Jpql is executing the query `select qp.query_plan from sys.dm_exec_requests r cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(r.plan_handle) qp where r.session_id <> @@SPID`

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface for your response. I have updated my question with query plan url at bottom.

Comment: Try an index `risk_violation (job_id, bname)`, there isn't much else you can do. can you upload an "actual" execution plan from SSMS? How many rows is the final resultset, I can't see from the estimated plan?

Comment: Added index as you suggested, but still same. I am not sure I am correctly running query plan. This time I have selected "Include Actual Execution Plan" and "Include Live Query Statistics" options on tool bar and executed. Please see the updated question with new query plans.

Comment: Now, I got to know how to get actual query plan. Give me few minutes, I will add that.

Comment: @Charlieface, I have updated my question with "Actual Execution Plan". Please check now.

Comment: @Charlieface, this time I am seeing "Actual Rows" with value of 440 in query plan. Please check latest attached query plan.

Comment: FYI, Current environment (Test system) is not having even 1%  records of Production environment.

Comment: OK we can safely establish it's not the query plan, given the small number of rows. Sorry can't help you further

Comment: @Charlieface, it worked after avoiding facade class b/w Java class (where my business logic resides) and JPA repository( use to execute JPQL queries). Directly invoked JPA repository method from Java class. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after avoiding facade class between Java class (where my business logic resides) and JPA repository( use to execute JPQL queries). Directly invoked JPA repository method from Java class. Not sure why it did not work with facade class with SQL Server, but same worked with MySQL database.